# Problema para direccionar multiple servidores

Tags: server, networking

En mi casa tengo un servidor dedicado y 4 raspberry pi,
En la ip 10.0.0.21 tengo un servidor de minecraft con el puerto 25565
en la ip 10.0.0.221 tengo otro servidor de minecraft mismo puerto 25565
Tengo un dominio pagado que es ciruelita.net, minecraft.ciruelita.net apunta a mi ip y lo mismo minecraft2.cirulita.net pero claro aca me falta algo ecencial que es el enrutador o balanceador de cargas para decirle que ip tiene que reaccionar ante tal llamado y no he encontrado nada, alguien sabe que puedo utilizar para dirigir mi trafico a determinada url.

Comment: Pues usas un nginx, un apache http o cualquier otro servidor HTTP que puedas poner a atender peticiones y configurarle nodos/workers/servicios que atienda.

Comment: Nunca realize algo asi tenes alguna pagina de documentacion ?

Comment: Segun veo, si intento acceder a minecraft.ciruelita.net:25565 me devuelve algo, por lo tanto entiendo que ya estas redirigiendo ese puerto a uno de esos dos raspberries, digamos que es el 10.0.0.21 por ejemplo.  No se si por obligacion minecraft debe responder siempre a ese puerto, pero si no es así yo iria al router y le redireccionaria otro puerto, por ejemplo, 25566, que apuntara al puerto 25565 de tu raspberry 10.0.0.221 y usaria minecraft.ciruelita.net:25566 como segundo servidor (así evitas hacer cosas raras con los nombres, pues aunque tengas muchos nombres, de IP solo tienes una).